# Getting Thumbnail from an external URL

Tags: php, html

I need to retreive image from an external link using php. I am not interested to use services like Embed.ly
I tried this one: https://www.webslake.com/article/generating-link-preview-using-php/

But it failed to get the image. Just showing the alt text.

Please help me to solve this problem...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you consider hiring someone to solve this?

Comment: I have tried the code given in the link

Comment: You need to give us more info on how it failed. What happened, what errors did you get, and what website URL did you try it on?

Comment: The Image is failed to be retrieved. It is blank just showing the alt text. And showing: Description Not Found

Comment: I can't help you if you don't answer all of the questions I asked.

Comment: Okay, I tried with https://twitter.com

Comment: Your code is looking for an `og:image` or `twitter:image` meta tag, and then for image tags. Twitter.com has none of these if you view the source as a logged-out user.

Comment: Facebook can't find an image for Twitter.com, either. There isn't one. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2F

Comment: I just tried with stackoverflow.com and this is same now

Comment: If you see, the code is finding for all tags including 'img'. Then retreiving the src(link) from that. Then why this failed here??

Comment: I tried with Hostinger.com, which works fine

Comment: Yes, it failed because twitter.com doesn't have any matching elements.

Comment: Okay, it maybe... i just tried a few more url and found that you are right  can you answer it below? So that I cqn give a good ending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is looking for an `og:image` or `twitter:image` meta tag, and then (as a fallback) for large image tags.

Twitter.com has none of these if you view the source as a logged-out user. There's no image for your code to fetch, so it fails to do so. This won't be uncommon, so it'd be best to have a "if no image is found" fallback in your code.